# Colloids and Ions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, phase

Suppose I have this reaction:
$$\ce{3NaOH(aq) + FeCl3(aq) → 3NaCl(aq) + Fe(OH)3}$$

My questions:

1. $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ doesn't have the (aq) suffix because it isn't separated in water as opposed to $\ce{NaCl}$?
2. Will the $\ce{3NaCl(aq)}$ be separated in positive and negative ions that will aggregate to the $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ producing colloids ?

Comment: "Separated" is a wrong word; use "dissociated" instead. Fe(OH)3 isn't soluble and therefore precipitates, hence no "(aq)".

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: You are correct. $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$ is not soluble in water meaning it will exist as a separate solid phase and thus it has no (aq) designation.

Question 2: It is correct that $\ce{NaCl}$ is soluble in water and will dissociate into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions in aqueous solution. Thus it has the (aq) designation. Also, aqueous $\ce{NaCl}$ can stabilize colloidal $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$.